# SQL 2008 filestream

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to retrieve the filename for filegroup filestream?

I try to create a new database in tsql, i need to create the filestream path for the database.

but i dont know the path of the folder to put the filestream in. So i try to get the filename path of another database on the same server to configure the new database.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

will show you all the database files in the current database - one of them is the one used for FILESTREAM storage, and should tell you what directory it's using.

```
SELECT physical_name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 2
```

Marc

Comment: The only informations this query return it's the name, dsata_space_id, type, type_desc, isdefault, filegroup_guid, log_filegroup_id and is_read_only column ... but no path

Answer (score 0):

Try querying a field storing a filestream in a table of the other DB like this

select top 1 fieldname.PathName from tablename